Mu4e auto completion not working
When I compose a message in mu4e and hit the tab key in the to: field only a tab is inserted and no address completion list pops up, even when I start a name and then hit tab.
I don't have the variable or so set to nil
What could I be missing here?
Mu4e-contacts shows a buffer with email addresses and names in a separate buffer though..

Make sure the correct completion function is called when you press Tab. In a working case for me, it called message-tab.
You could try the following: Compose a message, go to the To: field and try M-x message-tab. If this shows the list of emails you are expecting, then you know that either the keybinding itself is a problem or the function you are calling has an issue.
The reason why the correct function is not called when you press Tab is probably hidden somewhere in the packages you are using. But that is just a guess on my part.
PS: If you are using org-msg, then the function called is org-msg-tab which is just a thin wrapper around the above. So you can also try M-x org-msg-tab. See also: https://github.com/jeremy-compostella/org-msg/issues/166.
